# What does "as dissimilar as" mean?

Tags: as

> Types of information as dissimilar as language, music, and genomes can be represented as sequential data.

([Machine Learning on Sequential Data Using a Recurrent Weighted Average, Introduction](http://arxiv.org/abs/1703.01253))

In my understanding, "as dissimilar as" means "unlike", but in this situation, they seem to use "as dissimilar as" as "like",
because language, music, or genomes are sequential data.

What does "as dissimilar as" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to understand it pretty well.  *Superficially*, language, music, and genomes seem very different (dissimilar) types of information, but all can be represented as sequential data.